# Minimum version required of Amplify CLI is not installed in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, npm, aws-amplify

warning: AmplifyTools has been deprecated.

More info: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ios/blob/main/AmplifyTools/README.md

error: Minimum version required of Amplify CLI is not installed.

Min required version: (4.22.0)
Found Version: ([0m5.1.0[0m)

To install the latest version, please run the following command:
npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli@latest

As we can see found version is latest, but it is not taking.

when I checked in terminal amplify version:
[image]

Comment: Hi Satish. Were you able to figure this out? I am facing the same issue.